# Every nonnegative measurable function is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm reading a book on measure theory and during a section about integration the author states the following: *"Note that a nonnegative measurable function is always integrable"*. I tried proving it, but with no success. I know it suffices to show that upper integral $\leq$ lower integral (see below). Any help would be appreciated.

Background:

i) Any measurable function $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ can be decomposed as

$$
f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\chi_{A_n} \, ,
$$
where the sets $A_n\subseteq X$ are measurable.

ii) A function whose image is a countable subset of $[-\infty,\infty]$ is called a simple function. The integral of a nonnegative simple measurable function $g$ is defined as
$$
\int g \, d\mu = \sum_{0\leq y\leq\infty} y\mu(g^{-1}(\{y\}))
$$

iii) Given a function $f:X\to[-\infty,\infty]$, the upper and lower integrals are defined as

$$
\int^{\ast} f \, d\mu := \inf\left\{ \int g \, d\mu \, ; \, g \, \text{simple}, \text{integrable}, g\geq f \, \mu\text{-a.e.} \right\}
$$

$$
\int_{\ast} f \, d\mu := \sup\left\{ \int g \, d\mu \, ; \, g \, \text{simple}, \text{integrable}, g\leq f \, \mu\text{-a.e.} \right\}
$$
In case that $f$ is a measurable function, if its upper and lower integrals are equal, we say that $f$ is integrable and write
$$
\int f \, d\mu := \int_{\ast} f \, d\mu = \int^{\ast} f \, d\mu \, .
$$

Comment: By integrable, do you mean that we can make sense of the symbol $\int f\, d\mu$ (which if $f$ is nonnegative is an extended real number.) As opposed to say $\int_{\mathbb R} x \,dx$ which is not defined?

Comment: Yes, precisely. @AndrewZhang

Comment: In measure theory a measurable function $f$ is called integrable if $\int |f|d\mu <\infty$. You should try to use standard terminology so that people can understand your question properly.

Comment: I suspect that the author actually meant that for a nonnegative measurable $f$ the expression $\int fd\mu$ is always well defined (eventually taking value $+\infty$). This cannot be said of every measurable function.

Comment: Are you reading H. Federer's *Geometric measure theory*? His notion of integrability is the one you are describing (this is not standard terminology! What 99% of mathematicians call *integrable* is called *summable* in Federer's terminology). See 2.4.4(2) for the proof you are requesting.

Comment: Thanks @vizietto. I'm reading Evans' _Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions_. The chapter on general measure theory in Federer's book covers a lot of stuff that Evans doesn't, I'm definitely gonna use it as a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are reading *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions - Evans*, and your question is in page25.

Given the "i)" --  "Decomposition of nonnegative measurable functions" in page19 you listed above, it suffices to prove the question. The basic idea of the proof is to use the decomposition to prove the inequality:
$$\int_{*} fd\mu \geq \int^{*} fd\mu$$
but it's a little tricky, here is the proof:

1)$\mu(f=+\infty)>0\ $or$\ \exists n\in N_{+}\ s.t.\ \mu(A_n)=+\infty$

If $\mu(f=+\infty)>0$, any simple function $g$ s.t. $g\geq f, \mu-a.e.$ must have $\mu(g=+\infty) > 0$, and it implies:
$$\int^{*}fd\mu \geq \int_{*}fd\mu \geq (+\infty) * \mu(g=+\infty) = +\infty$$
$$\Rightarrow \int^{*}fd\mu = \int_{*}fd\mu = +\infty$$
therefore f is integrable.

If $\exists n\in N_{+}\ s.t.\ \mu(A_n)=+\infty$, simple function $\frac{1}{n}\chi_{A_n} \leq f$, and therefore:
$$\int^{*}fd\mu \geq \int_{*} fd\mu \geq \int \frac{1}{n}\chi_{A_n} d\mu = \frac{1}{n} * \mu(A_n) = +\infty$$
$$\Rightarrow \int^{*}fd\mu = \int_{*} fd\mu = +\infty$$
which implies $f$ is integrable.

2)$\mu(f=+\infty)=0\ $and$\ \forall n\in N_{+}\ \mu(A_n)<+\infty$

Now we can dismiss the part that $f=+\infty$ and only consider the bounded part of $f$, since the simple funcitons required in the lower and upper integral only require a.e. inequality.

Given the decomposition:
$$f=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n} \chi_{A_n}$$
we have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n} \chi_{A_n} \leq f \quad \forall k \in N_{+}$$
and $\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n} \chi_{A_n}$ is simple function by definition, so we have:
$$\begin{align}
\int_{*}fd\mu &\geq \int \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n} \chi_{A_n} d\mu  \\\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^{g(k)} y_n\mu(f^{-1}(B_n)) \quad \forall k \in N_{+}
\end{align}$$
where $B_n = \{x|f(x)=y_n, y_n\in Image(\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n} \chi_{A_n})\}, g(k)\subseteq N_{+}, g(k)\geq k\ $ ($\{A_n\}$ are not disjoint), and $\mu(B_n)<+\infty$, since $B_n \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^k A_n$ and $\forall n\leq k,\ \mu(A_n)<+\infty$
let $k \rightarrow +\infty$, we have:
$$\int_{*}fd\mu \geq \sum_{0\leq y_n\leq +\infty} y_n\mu(f^{-1}(B_n))$$
where $B_n = \{x|f(x)=y_n, y_n\in Image(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n} \chi_{A_n})\}$

Since $f < +\infty \ a.e.$ and $f=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n} \chi_{A_n}$, we have:
$$\forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists N\in N_{+}\ s.t.\ \forall k>N\quad f\leq \epsilon + \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}\chi_{A_n}\quad a.e.\ \forall k \in N_{+}$$
therefore:
$$\begin{align} \int^{*}fd\mu &\leq \int \epsilon + \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}\chi_{A_n}d\mu \\\\ &= \sum_{n=1}^{g(k)} y_n\mu(f^{-1}(B_n)) + \sum_{n=1}^{g(k)} \epsilon \mu(f^{-1}(B_n)) \quad \forall k \in N_{+} \end{align}$$
let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}$, we have:
$$\int^{*}fd\mu \leq \sum_{n=1}^{g(k)} y_n\mu(f^{-1}(B_n))\quad \forall k \in N_{+}$$
then let $k\rightarrow +\infty$, we have:
$$\int^{*}fd\mu \leq \sum_{0\leq y_n\leq +\infty} y_n\mu(f^{-1}(B_n))$$

Combine two inequalities above, we have:
$$\int_{*} fd\mu \geq \sum_{0\leq y_n\leq +\infty} y_n\mu(f^{-1}(B_n))\geq \int^{*}fd\mu$$
which implies $f$ is integrable.

I hope you find this proof helpful.